# set default value of select in jinja2 and show it after refresh page

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have a select item with jinja2 and it's something like this.

```
<select name="ChooseOne">
     {% for item in list %}
        <option value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>
```

now I want that when the user selects an item from this list it set for the default value of my select and it shows for the first choice of select if I refresh the page.
what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Have a separate variable passed to the template which is the id of the item to be selected.

```
<select name="ChooseOne">
     {% for item in list %}
        <option value="{{item.id}}"
        {% if item.id is selected_id %}
            selected
        {% endif %}

        >{{item.name}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: selected_id in if statement should not be in {{}}?

Comment: No, as it is within the {% %} tags.

Comment: unfortunately not worked! I check the item.id and selected_id was equal but not show in template :(

Comment: Try changing `is` to `==`